# Stuck on splash screen on boot, can't type into tty terminal

Tags: boot, plymouth, tty

After some upgrades (I believe it was for Ubuntu 12.04, wasn't me that ran the upgrade), the boot process became stuck on the splash screen (purple, dots moving along). Presuming the desktop manager to have not started, I hit Ctrl Alt F2 to fix it but although it seemed correct based on the output to think that the desktop manager had not started, I was unable to type into the tty terminal to run any commands, thus preventing me from continuing the troubleshooting process. While I probably could boot using a LiveUSB and manually edit some configs to fix the initial problem, I would like to know how to reenable the tty terminal input.

Comment: Do you by chance have a Happy Hacking Lite keyboard?

Comment: I do not; I use a Zowie Celeritas. However, I do recall having problems with plugging it in via USB instead of PS/2 so I will quickly put on an adapter and check if that helps anything.

Answer (score -1):

Changing my keyboard converter from USB to PS/2 fixed the problem of being unable to type into the tty screen. Now I have an additional problem of being unable to log in correctly but I doubt that's related so this question is done with. Thanks mttdbrd for leading me on the right track.